# get route is correct but api is still not working(fetching nothing)

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to make a get route for this API:

https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/opportunity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=92Ll6nGuQhfGjZnT2gxaUgiBhlCJ9K1zi2Fv5ONn

And although the syntax for the get route, the API still doesn't work in postman nor in client-side.

Here's the get route code:

```
app.get('/roverInfo/:rover_name', async (req, res) => {
  const { rover_name } = req.params

  try {
    let images = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/${rover_name}/photos?sol=1000&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`).then((res) => res.json())
    res.send({ images })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error:', err)
  }
})
```

[sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-noyce-qoh1q?file=/src/public/index.html)

and here's the client-side request:

```
const showRovers = async (rovers) => {
  try {
    await fetch(`https://localhost:3000/roverInfo/:rover_name`)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((rovers) => updateStore(store, { rovers }), console.log(rovers))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('errors:', error)
  }
}
```

and here's the error I am getting:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Comment: You have `https` when connecting to localhost, is that right?

Comment: @paintopi I fixed it but I am still getting no result

Comment: In your client request, you need to fill in an actual value for `rover_name`.  So, don't request `https://localhost:3000/roverInfo/:rover_name`.  Instead, put in an actual value in place of `:rover_name`, like `https://localhost:3000/roverInfo/myrover` or whatever the rover name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ADVISE: Don't mix await/async with .then, use either one**

```
app.get("/roverInfo/:rover_name", async (req, res) => {
  const { rover_name } = req.params;

  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/${rover_name}/photos?sol=1000&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    ) // removed .then
    const images = await res.json(); // await response to json
    res.send({ images });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error:", err);
  }
});
```

**02. should be http instead of https**

**03. need to pass rover name to param instead of using `:rover_name`**

```
let getRovers = showRovers('opportunity');

const showRovers = async (roverName) => {
  try {
    console.log("roverName", roverName)
    // use http here
    await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/roverInfo/${roverName}`) 
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((rovers) => updateStore(store, { rovers }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("errors:", error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I implemented that now but looks like there's something missing because nothing is fetched so far

Comment: i updated the answer with `await res.json();`. have you changed that?

Comment: yes and unfortunately I am getting false for rovers

Comment: updated answer, the frontend is not passing rover name to backend. the `:rover_name` should be replaced on frontend with roverName

Comment: While the advice of not mixing `.then()` and `await` is generally sound, the way this code is written in that regard is not causing any problems and changing that is not the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: And there is problem of getting rover name in `showRovers()` method as well where you pass the whole array to it. I just hardcode the rover name first - `let getRovers = showRovers('opportunity');` to let's you test it.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes. but it is a advise and the problem is the frontend `:rover_name` name is not being replaced which stated in the comment. Just no time to change the answer while replying '''

Comment: I tried the updated answer and it caused that error:: ReferenceError: roverName is not defined

Comment: strange. can you console.log the roverName to see if it can print `'opportunity'` out

Comment: @jfriend00 Although aligning async/await is not a "solution", it is also important to remind people to take care of it, do you think so ? What is the problem on stating that in the answer?

Comment: It's OK to mention it as an aside, but it is NOT part of the actual solution to the problem.  The way your answer is presented, it looks like it's a required and most important part of the solution.  It has nothing at all to do with the actual problem in the question.  And, in this particular case, there's nothing wrong with `let value = await fetch(...).then((res)=> res.json());` at all.  That structure (mixing `await` and `.then()`) works perfectly fine here.  So, making it the most prominent part of your answer and making it appear like it's required is both misleading and wrong.

Comment: Not everyone is a perfect english writer. My english may confuse you and other to think that way. Anyway, I will double check my wording before posting. And I think it is a must to use either await/async or .then, not to mix it up in my opinion.